# is it safe to ftruncate a shared memory object after it has ben mmap'ed?

Tags: linux, memory-management, posix, shared-memory

- `shm_open()`
- `mmap()` with a predefined big `length`
- `fork()` (several times)
- `ftruncate()` at will

The point of this is to make sure that every process spawned by `fork()` have a shared segment at the same address. Yet, I don't want to keep the RAM busy all the time, but dynamically resize it (with size spanning 0 - big `length`).

Can this work? Is there UB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that's fine. You can truncate the underlying file anytime, but you may receive `SIGBUS` if you access the memory beyond the file's bounds. So, you will need to be extremely careful not to touch memory beyond the current length of the file (or catch `SIGBUS` and deal with it).

From `man 2 mmap`:

> Use of a mapped region can result in these signals:
>
> `SIGBUS` Attempted access to a portion of the buffer that does not correspond to
>                 the file (for example, beyond the end of the file, including the case
>                 where another process has truncated the file).

Comment: That's what I'd assume, but could the `munmap` trigger writes to dirty pages which might trigger a `SIGBUS`?

Comment: Marking this as accepted, because it answers my question. But Damon's method is better manageable (I can unload pages in the middle of the `mmap`ed range).

Comment: @nneonneo I don't think this is quite right. I believe you need to do an `mremap` after the `ftruncate` to update the mapping. Nonetheless you should still allocate a large size originally to prevent `mremap` failing with `ENOMEM`.

Comment: @jleahy: Actually, my point is that you don't need to `mremap`, but accessing memory past the end of the file may cause a crash. In practice, `mremap` is safer.

Comment: @nneonneo What about if another process shares a mapping of the file? Then one process can launch a denial of service attack on the other by ftruncating the file smaller and triggering SIGBUS in the innocent process (surely Linux does not allow this?)

Comment: @Eloff: The other process should not have (write) access to the file at all. If it did, then there's all manner of nastier things you can do (e.g. overwriting code sections in-memory to force the other program to execute arbitrary code).

Answer (score 1):

Don't resize it.

> I don't want to keep the RAM busy all the time

That's what the kernel will do for you with virtual memory.  It will be paged as necessary/appropriate as long as you don't use `mlock()` or `MAP_LOCKED`.

Comment: well, RAM as well as swap. I might use something in the middle of the mapped area at some time (forcing the kernel to commit it), but then I could forget about it for the rest of the runtime. So I think I need a way to explicitly tell that I'm no more using that part of the address space.

Comment: You can use `madvise()`, but be aware that there's no guarantees on the behavior.

Comment: I guess I would use `MADV_REMOVE`. But then what should I do if I need back that space?

Comment: Without knowing more details, I'd think you'd prefer `MADV_DONTNEED`.

Answer (score 1):

Create mappings as large as you like, it will not "keep RAM busy" unless you actually use it.

If you are worried about keeping RAM busy *after you are done* using it, call `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)` -- this will purge the pages and give you back new pages from the zero pool if you access them again.

Comment: There's no operation that I need to perform before writing to a a range that has been marked as `MADV_DONTNEED`, right?

Comment: Note that the zero fill behavior is only in cases where the backing store no longer has those pages (as it might be in the question where some of the data could have been discarded by `ftruncate`).

Comment: @LorenzoPistone: There is nothing you have to do, no. `MADV_DONTNEED` will discard the pages and either (if backed by a file) reload pages from disk transparently as needed, or (anon mapping) just throw a zero page at you. Note that the latter is -- at least in my opinion -- actually "incorrect" behaviour, since POSIX states that semantics are _not_ changed (which is quite the case!). It's just what you want, though.